# Bloomberg's Open Market Data Initiative

Tags: programming, data, market-data, bloomberg

I am reading about OMDI:
https://www.bloomberg.com/company/announcements/bloomberg-opens-its-data-distribution-technology/

After reading that, I am still not sure:
Is it free?
If so, what kind of data are there?
Can I download compiled data from companies' earnings reports? And from stock markets?
Or is it rather a data bus for companies to send data to, for potential subscribers?
If so, how can I know about data publishers?

I have tried the API following the examples, against `open.bloomberg.com`, but all I was able to get was `Unauthorized` or `Unknown service` or such.

What it seems to me as is that Bloomberg is essentially asking others, "this is how we store our data internally, please publish them in the same way." Correct?

Lastly, should this question go rather to Open Data StackExchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API and its documentation have been open sourced and are publicly available, but to connect to and download data from the Bloomberg database you need a Bloomberg subscription.